Issue with enabling perfLoggingPrefs in Selenium (Python)
I am trying to start an instance of the chrome webdriver through Selenium that tracks outgoing HTTP requests.
I have the following code (excerpted)
#imports removed for brevity

class ConfiguredWD(WD.Chrome):

    def __init__(self, logging):
        chrome_options = WD.ChromeOptions()
        
        #options arguments removed for brevity

        chrome_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
        chrome_capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
        chrome_capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
        if logging:
            chrome_capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {
                'performance'        : 'ALL',
                'level'              : 'INFO',
                'browser'            : 'ALL'},
            chrome_options.add_experimental_option('perfLoggingPrefs', {
                'enableNetwork'  : True,
                #'logType'        : 'PERFORMANCE',
                #"performance"    : "ALL",
                'traceCategories': 'devtools.Network.requestWillBeSent',
                'enablePage'     : False
            })
        #chrome_options.set_capability = chrome_capabilities
        chrome_service = WD.ChromeService(executable_path = r"path\to\executable.exe")
        super().__init__(options = chrome_options, service = chrome_service) 

...

When initializing this class, I receive the following error: "InvalidArgumentException()"
with the following message: "'invalid argument: perfLoggingPrefs specified, but performance logging was not enabled'"
Can anyone help debug this error?
Looking through the Selenium documentation and Google's documentation on ChromeDevTools API. I have also consulted prior stackOverflow questions, but these are from several years ago and the API seems to have changed.
